# How to read line by line from a file in Haskell

Tags: haskell

im trying to make a programm that should read line by line from a file and check if its a palindrom, if it is, then print.

I'm really new to haskell so the only thing i could do is just print out each line, with this code :

```
main ::  IO()
  main = do
  filecontent <- readFile "palindrom.txt"
  mapM_ putStrLn (lines filecontent)

isPalindrom w = w==reverse w
```

The thing is, i dont know how to go line by line and check if the line is a palindrom ( note that in my file, each line contains only one word). Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one suggested approach

```
main ::  IO()
main = do
  filecontent <- readFile "palindrom.txt"
  putStrLn (unlines $ filter isPalindrome $ lines filecontent)

isPalindrome w = w==reverse w
```

The part in parens is pure code, it has type `String->String`.  It is generally a good idea to isolate pure code as much as possible, because that code tends to be the easiest to reason about, and often is more easily reusable.

You can think of data as flowing from right to left in that section, broken apart by the `($)` operators.  First you split the content into separate lines, then filter only the palindromes, finally rebuild the full output as a string.  Also, because Haskell is lazy, even though it looks like it is treating the input as a single `String` in memory, it actually is only pulling the data as needed.

---

Edited to add extra info....

OK, so the heart of the soln is the pure portion:

```
unlines $ filter isPalindrome $ lines filecontent
```

The way that `($)` works is by evaluating the function to the right, then using that as the input of the stuff on the left.  In this case, `filecontent` is the full input from the file (a `String`, including newline chars), and the output is STDOUT (also a full string including newline chars).

Let's follow sample input through this process, "abcba\n1234\nK"

```
unlines $ filter isPalindrome $ lines "abcba\n1234\nK"
```

First, lines will break this into an array of lines

```
unlines $ filter isPalindrome ["abcba", "1234", "K"]
```

Note that the output of lines is being fed into the input for filter.

So, what does filter do?  Notice its type

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

This takes 2 input params, the first is a function (which `isPalendrome` is), the second a list of items.  It will test each item in the list using the function, and its output is the same list input, minus items that the function has chosen to remove (returned `False` on).  In our case, the first and third items are in fact palendromes, the second not.  Our expression evaluates as follows

```
unlines ["abcba", "K"]
```

Finally, `unlines` is the opposite of `lines`....  It will concatinate the items again, inserting newlines in between.

```
"abcba\nK"
```

Since STDIO itself is a `String`, this is ready for outputting.

Note that is it perfectly OK to output a list of `String`s using non-pure functions, as follows

```
forM ["1", "2", "3"] $ \item -> do
    putStrLn item
```

This method however mixes pure and impure code, and is considered slightly less idiomatic Haskell code than the former.  You will still see this type of thing a lot though!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, can you please explain a little more about how do the "$" operator and the function filter work?  

As far as i understand, the filter check if "isPalindrome" in each line of filecontents, if its true, then print, right ? So why would i need unlines here ? 

Many thanks !

Comment: I've added more detail.

Comment: One more question, now if i want to say "...  is a palindrome" everytime i found a palindrom, where should i add the ".. is a palindrome" part ? I can't say how much thanksful i am:)

Comment: In the pure method, you can just add to each individual string in the pipeline using `map`, like this `unlines $ map (++ " is a palindrome") $ filter isPalindrome $ lines fileContent`.  With the monadic approach, you can just add to the `putStrLn`, like this `putStrLn $ item ++ " is a palendrome"`.  In this case, the monadic approach is probably much easier to understand, although I still like to keep things pure.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the `filter` function. You may not want to put all processing on a single line, but use a *let* expression. Also, your indentation is off:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  filecontent <- readFile "palindrom.txt"
  let selected = filter ... filecontent
  ...
```